# Column-dependent selection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql

I have a database table with `vehicles` in it and they're separated into columns by `year`, `make`, `model`, and `trim`.

I'd like to create a form where a user can select the `year`, then the `make`, then the `model`, then the `trim` with each selection (except for `year`) taking into consideration the  selection before it.

Is there a way to do this?  What would it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have lots of different ways to do it.

I would do the following way:

```
$("#year']").click(function(){
  var url = '/get_make_values?year=' + $(this).val()
  $("#group").removeOption(/./)
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#group').addOption(data, false);
  });
});
```

In your controller,

```
def get_make_values
  val = params[:year]
  #Use val to find records
  options = Vehicles.collect{|x| "'#{x.id}' : '#{x.label}'"}    
  render :text => "{#{options.join(",")}}" 
end
```

In your models you can define some scopes:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_year, lambda {|v| where(:year => year)}
  ...
end
```

Hope this helps!

Regards

**Edit:**

I'll explain in parts

In the **javascript** I'm associating an event to the list of year, then I make a GET request to a controller action that get all make values. Then I fill the MAKE list with it
You should do it to make, model and trim also

In the **controller** I'm creating a method to retrieve the make values (that is called by the get method). You'll have to do it for the other retrieved values also. Model and trim.

In the **model** I just suggested a resource that you may use to facilitate the queries that is the scope feature.

Please accept my reply!

Comment: Thanks!  I have to admit though, this is a little over my head... Can you expand on what's being done here?

Comment: I'll explain in parts

-
In the Javascript I'm associating an event to the list of year, then I make a GET request to a controller action that get all make values. Then I fill the MAKE list with it

You should do it to make, model and trim also
-

In the controller I'm creating a method to retrieve the make values (that is called by the get method). You'll have to do it for the other retrieved values also. Model and trim.
-

In the model I just suggested a resource that you may use to facilitate the queries that is the scope feature.
-

Please accept my reply!